# siunitx with reciprocal option misses \cdot between numerator and denominator

Tags: siunitx

I have a minimal example of an `siunitx` usage which has some unwanted behavior, maybe a little bug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIQualifier{\cat}{cat}

\begin{document}

\si[per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first]{\mole\square\meter\per\second\per\kilogram\cat}

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Actually there should be a multiplication sign between the numerator and the denominator. Am I doing something wrong or does somebody agree with me that `siunitx` is behaving strangely?

Comment: If I use 

per-mode=reciprocal

it works fine but why not with the other option?

Comment: Yes: a bug. I suspect I'll not make any further changes to the 2.x branch as I'm working on v3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it is a bug report which should be done on the maintainers issue trackers. (Added this one here: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/288)

Comment: @JosephWright: Since you don't plan to fix the bug in 2.x (it is still open), why don't you mention the bug in the [manual](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf)